# Android Studio occasionally doesn't start

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

I used to have only the stable version of AS installed (AS 4.0), and occasionally it wouldn't start. It would show it's loading screen, but then that's it. If I hover over the AS icon in the status bar, it shows a blank (white) screen. It will however present the 'tips' window. I had to uninstall/reinstall it, which sometimes took several tries until successful. This would fix the problem, but is not a solution.

Now I have the preview beta installed side by side (AS 4.1-beta4), and it is that version that occasionally has problems starting, and the stable version has interestingly become, well, stable.

I have my JAVA_HOME environment variable as: C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\jre\bin and added a second one just now just in case: C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio-preview\android-studio\jre\bin

I had a JDK_HOME variable as well, but deleted it after I read it was redundant. It didn't change anything. I'm using Windows 10

Update:
I now notice this problem occurs only when a specific project wasn't closed properly due to the computer's battery running out or a Windows crash. Should I delete one of the folders or files in order to 'reset' the project for a clean Android Studio build?

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK, Oracle JDK, or bundled (AFAIK OpenJDK-based) JDK?

Comment: Bundled - openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"

Comment: You might try running Studio from the command prompt and see what messages come up. It will have a bunch even normally, but there might be some messages that appear around when it is getting stuck that will give you more clues. Also, for the long-term benefit of the question... could you edit it and say exactly what versions you are using?

Comment: What are your system specifications?

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the versions. Running from cmd...where am I supposed to see messages exactly?

Comment: Directly in the terminal window. For example, with 4.2 Canary 7, I get hundreds upon hundreds of lines dumped in the terminal window where I ran `bin/studio.sh` (I'm on Linux).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm on windows right now. I ran AS from CMD. How can I see the logs?

Comment: They would be showing up in the window where you ran `bin/studio.bat` (or whatever the command is for Windows to start Studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the .idea folder caused Android Studio to rebuild the project and open correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If Your operating system is Windows then try to change JDK (Sun, OpenJDK) etc. and for other operating system download stable version with jdk and create desktop icon permanently don't run from terminal.

Comment: I'm not running from terminal

Answer (score 1):

You could be running into a Java running out of memory while AS loads. To change the available memory that AS can allocate, perform the following steps:

1. Open AS successfully
2. From the main menu, select Help | Change Memory Settings
3. Increase the maximum amount of memory that you want to allocate (try doubling it) and then click Save and restart.

This should rule out any JVM heap issues